# LightSwitch Controls Keypress events

Tags: javascript, events, .net-4.0, visual-studio-lightswitch

I want a way to capture the keypress events on my controls and if it's an Enter, set focus to the next control.

We had to do this once in a simple ASP.NET application to allow users to navigate through the controls by pressing enter on a Web Environment. We used a simple JavaScript back then.

Is there a way to accomplish this? If it envolves creating custom controls, are the LightSwitch control's classes available so I can inherit them all or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it for a large number of controls, you'd be better of creating a custom control (preferably a control extension - binding is automatic), but you're going to need to create several different controls I'd imagine, not just a TextBox.

Of course it's up to you, but you might find it easier to just explain to/teach your end-users that "Tab" goes to the next control, "Enter" does not. This is the way that most Windows applications work, so you'd be going *with* the flow, instead of *against* it. There's a reason it's called "tab order".

Sorry, I know it's probably not what you wanted to hear, and you're not the first to ask for a way to do this, but as I said, you'd be going *against* the way that most, if not all, modern Windows software works, and it's not simple thing to do.

Comment: I know that, but what you said about teaching the end-users that tab goes to the next control, not enter, is REALLY not up to me, although it was my first suggestion. As you can see in my question, I've already had to do something similar in ASP.NET...